# Overridding GetHashCode and Equals in Castle Dynamic Proxy 2.1 IModelInterceptorsSelector

Tags: castle-windsor, castle, castle-dynamicproxy

I've read that in order to get caching and push performance when using an Interceptor Selector when using Castle Dynamic Proxy that I need to override GetType(), GetHashCode() and Equals()

Where can I find an example of or what would be the best, from a performing perspective, implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't override GetType, it's not virtual.

For the remaining ones, use the same technique you'd use for any other type.
I generally make my selectors stateless, and implement the methods as `this.GetType().GetHashCode()` and `This.GetType() == other.GetType()`

Comment: For stateless selectors something as simple as this: 
 public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
      return this.GetType() == obj.GetType();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
      return this.GetType().GetHashCode();
    }